# Using the iOS simulator to test websites

Tags: browser, ios, ios-simulator

I'd like to test a website with iOS. Is it possible to use the iOS simulator to run the iOS browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/02/17/apple_sdk_simulator_offers_closer_look_at_safari_for_ipad.html