# How can I test websites for Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, browser-testing

What can I use to test websites I developed using HTML/CSS to see how it looks in mobile devices like iPhone/iPad/Android? Emulators/Simulators on Windows? I could installthe Android SDK and use its emulator? for Apple's devices, I need to pay for the SDK? anything I can use to emulate, I just need it for website testing not apps. Sites like www.testiphone.com or iphonetester.com doesn't appear to be accurate

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854916/using-the-ios-simulator-to-test-websites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a Mac, use the iPhone simulator included with the SDK.

For windows, there's an Adobe AIR application called iBBDemo2 which is an iPad/iPhone simulator. It looks like a fairly accurate emulator, so it might be worth a try: [iBBDemo2](http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662)

EDIT: Just tested this out on a couple more sites and it's accurate. Definitely worth trying.

The Android SDK also includes an emulator and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need somekinda Apple iOS device to test it.

The SDK is free, if you have access to a modern Mac OSX machine.
Inside the iOS SDK which requires a Mac OSX, you have iPhone and iPad simulators.

You could also try to install a "hackintosh" (PC hardware with Mac OSX upon), then you would need a "spare PC" which is compatible with the hackintosh setup + an original Mac OSX DVD (very cheap actually).